# Superfish Menu in Wordpress header creating Scrollbars on dropdown

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, superfish, scrollbars

So I've tried looking through all of the posts on here, but I can't find my issue replicated anywhere (although that my speak more to my google abilities than to the uniqueness of my situation)

Basically I have a wordpress-based website (vegasonthemic.com) using the superfish plugin for the navigation menu. 
I'm able to access dropdown menu items in the top navigation bar on every page except for the individual artist post items. (All Artists/Acoustic Male/clicking one of the pictures.)

When I go to a page like this one: http://vegasonthemic.com/portfolio-item/nate-ridgely-2012-04-19/ and try to access the All Artists dropdown menu it doesn't show all the way in firefox and IE and in chrome it creates these gnarly scrollbars.

I've tried adjusting z-indexes and overflow:visible;s to my little heart's content and can't figure out why on earth this is happening.

Comment: Your whole content is not in a wrapper this may lead to so many issues and dont apply different css on same ID again and again.define all the css for particular id  at once

Comment: @TheGreenWayKid: always use only one id or class for define your styles in this case as told by Ankit you put a selector number of times its not a good practice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your css the container need a overflow visible like this

```
#container {
    width: 1280px;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: perfect user1347312. @ThatGreenwayKid: You have defined css for same selector in same css file at different locations - Too bad css.

Comment: PERFECT! Thanks so much for the quick feedback! This site is amazing! Now I'll have to go clean up some CSS. :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `overflow:auto;` from the container

```
#container {
     overflow: auto; /*Remove this*/(from style.css (line 121))}
```

Comment: no need to be sorry it's okay, you were right at your point..the guy who coded this need to put more efforts by using your solution. though he never get in trouble if he used proper css values from beginning